# Replace all values in array with their enumerated counterparts Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with the following structure

```
[[distance_1,intensity_1],[distance_2,intensity_2]...]
```

These distances have many decimal points, are unordered and are not unique. I want these distances to have values from 0-max_number_of_unique_values in integers.

An example:

```
array = [[-1.13243,3],[-0.71229,2],[-2.314532,9],[2.34235,4],[1.342545,4],[-1.13243,2]]
```

By enumerating all unique distance values I get the following mapping

```
enumerated_distances = np.array(list(enumerate(np.unique(array[:,0]))))
```

```
[[-2.314532,0],[-1.13243,1],[-0.71229,2],[1.342525,3],[2.34235,4]]
```

Now, what I want to do, is to replace all distance values with their enumerated counterparts, so the original array ends up like this:

```
[[1,3],[2,2],[0,9],[4,4],[3,4],[1,2]]
```

Is there a way of doing this efficiently in numpy, without manually finding each value and replacing it with its enumerated counterpart?

Performance is key, as this will be integrated into a system running in real time. In my example, there is only one distance (x), but in reality it will be three dimensional (x,y,z).

Comment: Are you trying to find duplicate elements indices? then use `return_inverse=True`  `np.unique(array[:,0], return_inverse=True)`

Comment: No, I am trying to replace all decimal distance values in my array with their enumerated counterparts. The reason for this is that these distances varies, but there are always the same number of points. Replacing the distances with their enumerated counterparts would thus make sure that lists with different distance increments are mapped to the same type of array.

Comment: Maybe it would be fast enough to do it manually and speed up the loop using something like `numba`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Epsi95 points out, this is just `np.unique(*, return_inverse = True)`

```
_, inv = np.unique(array[:,0], return_inverse = True)

enumerated_out = np.stack([inv, array[:, 1]], axis = -1).astype(int)

enumerated_out
Out[]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 9],
       [4, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2]])
```